# Does the rate of decay of an entire function dictate the global growth rate?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, growth-rate

If $f$ is entire and we assume a decay rate on $\mathbb{R}^+$, does this dictate a growth rate on $\mathbb{C}$?

For example, is there a function that decays as $e^{-x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and is of exponential type?

What I am actually interested in is whether there exists an entire function such that $|f(z)|\le Me^{-a z}$ for all $z>0$ and $ |f(z)| \le Me^{b |z|} $ for all $z$, with $b<a$.

Comment: It should also follow from Phragmen-Lindelof

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical walk-to-the-library problem. I used Boas, but probably other standard books would have worked too.

Boas proves the following results: (1) if $f$ is of order $1$, then $\limsup m(r)M(r)^{1+\epsilon}=\infty$ (Theorem 3.3.1); (2) if $f$ is of order $0<\rho<1$, then we obtain $m(r_n)\gtrsim M(r_n)^{-a}$ along a suitable sequence $r_n\to\infty$ from Theorem 3.2.11; (3) finally, if $f$ is of order $0$, then $\log m(r)\simeq \log M(r)$ on a suitable sequence again (Theorem 3.6.2).

So there is no such function.

(I've used the usual notations $m(r), M(r)$ for the min and max, respectively, of $|f|$ on $|z|=r$.)

Comment: Boas wrote several books. Which book are you quoting from?

Comment: @GHfromMO: Entire functions.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. For (2) we need some control on $a$, e.g. $a=1$ is admissible by Theorem 3.2.11.

Comment: @GHfromMO: It doesn't really matter, but I think any $a$ works fine, since we're assuming order $<1$ in (2), so $M(r)^{-a} \gtrsim e^{-a|z|^{1-\epsilon}}$.

Comment: You are right, and I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no. More generally, for functions of exponential type $b$ (which means $|f(z)|\leq Me^{b|z|}$), define the indicator:
$$h(\theta)=\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log|f(re^{i\theta})|}{r}.$$
Then there is a description of all possible indicators: they are trigonometrically convex:
$$h''+h\geq 0,$$
where derivatives should be understood in the generalized sense where they do not exist. Equivalently and more intuitively: possible indicators are exactly the support functions
of compact convex sets. From which follows that $\min h\geq -\max h$.

There are many deep generalizations of these things to functions which are not
necessarily of exponential type, and for decrease not necessarily on a straight line. For example, there is a theorem of Hayman and Kjellberg that for every
curve $\gamma$ tending to infinity,
$$\limsup_{z\to\infty,\;z\in\gamma}\frac{\log|f(z)|}{M(|z|)}\geq -1.$$
This holds for every non-constant entire function (not necessarily of exponential type).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer to your question but on top of my head : 
consider an entire function $f$ that goes to zero on $\mathbb R^+$, 
the function $z\mapsto f(1/z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C^*$. 
Since $f$ is going to zero via real values, we know this function is not meromorphic with a pole . Furthermore, it cannot be bounded otherwise it would be holomorphic on the riemann sphere thus constant. 
Finally, $f$ has an essential singularity at infinity.
However this does not answer your question.